# Find Duplicate number from a set of random numbers and print them without using ArrayList,HashMaps or any other collection

Tags: java

Below is the class that i have created to find the duplicate numbers but this code is printing the duplicate number more than once,can someone tweak this code to print the duplicate numbers only once

```
import java.util.Arrays;        

public class DuplicateNumbers{

public void printDuplicateNumber(int[] arr){

Arrays.sort(arr);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){

        if(arr[i]==arr[j]){

        System.out.println("duplicate numbers are "+arr[i]);

        break;

     }

    }

  }

}
```

}

```
public class TestDuplicateNumbers{

public static void main(String args[]){

    int[] arr={44,1,1,2,20,92,64,64,64,24,93,102,1,20131,22,64,1,20131};

    DuplicateNumbers dn = new DuplicateNumbers();

    dn.printDuplicateNumber(arr);


}
```

}

Comment: No, we won't do your homework. What could be the strategy to implement that? Have you thought about a solution?

Comment: lol! i have thought of a solution but it wont be feasible if the array contains a large value(for eg. 1002020)

Comment: And this solution is?

Comment: -create a boolean array(with size = maximum number of array)
-set the values as true wherever you find the duplicates
-use a loop print the index values which have TRUE values

Comment: Or maybe you could try a google or SO search for "java find duplicates" or "java duplicates". That should give you some ideas.

Comment: Why not use an integer array instead, containing all the already printed duplicates?

Comment: And what should i do with that array ?

Comment: add the already printed duplicates to it, and checking if it contains it before printing a new one. Not that this array could in fact be your original array: if the current number is already present before the current element, then you have already printed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing too much your code

```
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                while (j < arr.length && arr[i] == arr[j])
                    j++;
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
                i = j;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(arr);

for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if ((arr[i - 1] == arr[i]) && (arr[i + 1] != arr[i])) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}

if (arr[arr.length - 1] == arr[arr.length - 2]) {
    System.out.println(arr[arr.length - 1]);
}
```